# Agregar un búscador y categorías al estilo Google Maps pero en Mapbox

Tags: css, html5, responsive, mapbox

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para guardar la ubicación de unos sitios turísticos con la ayuda de la librería mapbox. pero deseo agregar en la parte superior de mi aplicación un búscador y las etiquetas al estilo de Google Maps. como lo veremos en la siguiente ilusatración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código de la construcción hasta ahora.(se debe insertar en un archivo HTML)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Lugares</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.4.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <!-- Aquí puedes agregar el resto del contenido de tu página -->
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Agrega tu token de Mapbox aquí
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZnQyeW14ZHdnaThzYmcifQ.w4Az8erXx-ejDc35snFDsg';

// Crea el mapa
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // Estilo predeterminado de Mapbox
    center: [-74.5, 40],
    zoom: 9 // Establece el nivel de zoom
```

Agradecería demasiado una ayuda, con esto ,para que también sea responsive si se carga en dispositivos móbiles. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¡El access token es información **sensible**! No debes compartirlo en un sitio público.